# Closed form of $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{x}\cos\left(\pi\left(n+1\right)\right)e^{\frac{x}{n}}dn$

Tags: definite-integrals

The [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/izi6dyuhpb) of $$ \int_{1}^{x}\cos\left(\pi\left(n+1\right)\right)e^{\frac{x}{n}}dn $$ looks really similar to $\Gamma(x)$ plus some sinusoidal function. Wolfram Alpha couldn't give an answer. Is there some way to evaluate this integral? Maybe in terms of the gamma function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\int_1^x {\cos (\pi (t + 1)){\rm e}^{x/t} {\rm d}t}  =  - \int_1^x {\cos (\pi t){\rm e}^{x/t} {\rm d}t}  =  - \int_{1/x}^1 {\frac{1}{{u^2 }}\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }{u}} \right){\rm e}^{xu} {\rm d}u} .
$$
Now assume that $x\ge 2$. We split the integral at $u=\frac{1}{2}$. Then
$$
\left| {\int_{1/x}^{1/2} {\frac{1}{{u^2 }}\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }{u}} \right){\rm e}^{xu} {\rm d}u} } \right| \le \frac{1}{2}x^2 {\rm e}^{x/2} .
$$
By [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma)
\begin{align*}
 - \int_{1/2}^1 {\frac{1}{{u^2 }}\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }{u}} \right){\rm e}^{xu} {\rm d}u} & =  - {\rm e}^x \int_0^{1/2} {\frac{1}{{(1 - t)^2 }}\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }{{1 - t}}} \right){\rm e}^{ - xt} {\rm d}t} 
\\ & \sim \frac{{{\rm e}^x }}{x}\left( {1 + \frac{2}{x} + \frac{{6 - \pi ^2 }}{{x^2 }} + \frac{{12(2 - \pi ^2 )}}{{x^3 }} +  \ldots } \right)
\end{align*}
as $x\to +\infty$. Accordingly,
$$
\int_1^x {\cos (\pi (t + 1)){\rm e}^{x/t} {\rm d}t}  \sim \frac{{{\rm e}^x }}{x}\left( {1 + \frac{2}{x} + \frac{{6 - \pi ^2 }}{{x^2 }} + \frac{{12(2 - \pi ^2 )}}{{x^3 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $x\to +\infty$. If you compare this with Stirling's formula for $\Gamma(x)$, you can see that your integral grows much slower than $\Gamma(x)$. Note also that the oscillatory contribution does not affect the value of the integral for large $x$.

Comment: Oh, that was cool indeed! Thank you, I learnt something.

Answer (score 3):

We use a cosine series:

$$-\int_1^x \cos(\pi n)e^\frac xn dn=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_1^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1} \pi^{2k} n^{2k}e^\frac xn }{(2k)!}dn$$

Using $n\to \frac 1n$ implies the [En function E$_v(z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=En%28v%2Cz%29) and [“generalized” incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(a,x,y)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gamma%28x%2Cy%2Cz%29) integral representations:

$$\int_1^x \cos(\pi n)e^\frac xn dn =x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k (\pi n)^{2k}\Gamma\left(-2k-1,-x,-\frac x n\right)}{(2k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k\pi^{2k}\left(n^{2k+1}\text E_{2k+2}\left(-\frac xn\right)-\text E_{2k+2}(-x)\right)}{(2k)!}$$

[Shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nintegrate%5Bcos%28pi+n%29+e%5E%28e%2Fn%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Ccatalan%7D%5D%2Csum%5B%28%28-1%29%5Ek+%CF%80%5E%282+k%29+e%5E%281+%2B+2+k%29+%28%CE%93%28-1+-+2+k%2C+-e%2C+-e%2Fcatalan%29%29%29%2F%28%282+k%29%21%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C20%7D%5D) is the gamma result. This series does not imply a closed form.

Comment: slight errors in the first eqn. : firstly it would be $-cos(\pi n)$, secondly you made a typo and wrote $(2l)!$ rather than $(2k)!$

Comment: @Hersh Thanks. At least the final result works

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\cos(\pi(n+1)) = -\cos(\pi n)$.

Don't know if this could help but as $x\to +\infty$ we have an asymptotic estimation for the integral:

$$\int_1^x e^{x/n} \cos(\pi n)\ \text{d}n \sim -x \text{Ei}(x)-\text{Ei}(1) x \cos (\pi  x)+e^x+e x \cos (\pi  x)$$

Where Ei is the Exponential Integral function. There is a relation between the Exponential Integral function and the incomplete Gamma Function:

$$E_n(x) = \int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{e^{-xt}}{t^n}\ \text{d}t \equiv x^{n-1} \Gamma(1-n, x)$$

There is a connection between Ei and $E_n$ too, but you will find more interesting the whole reading, like here as a start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Generalization

Comment: Do you mean $\mathrm{d} n$ in place of $\mathrm{d} x$? Also $\cos(\pi(n+1))=-\cos(\pi n)$.

Comment: Yes, sorry! Going to fix those errors!

Answer (score 1):

Maple also doesn't find a closed-form antiderivative.  This is the "pure transcendental" case, where Maple (and I think Mathematica/Wolfram Alpha too) should have a full implementation of the Risch algorithm, so I think we can be confident that there is no elementary antiderivative.  It's not impossible that there could be a closed-form antiderivative involving non-elementary functions such as $\Gamma$, but since neither Maple nor Wolfram Alpha find one , I think it's unlikely.

Comment: As a W. Mathematica user, I can confirm the non existence of a closed form in such sense.